# Object as a data member in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

From what I have experienced it seems as if objects cannot be shared data members in objective c. I know you can init a pointer and alloc the object in each method but I cannot seem to figure out how one can say define a NSMutableString as a data member and allow all of the methods to use and modify its data as in c++. Is this true or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you provide accessor methods for your NSMutableString, or declare it as a property?

Comment: Heh, this must be one of those blind spots everyone encounters when they learn new languages. You're so stuck in the forms of your own language you can't see something simple and obvious. You're going to kick yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to synthesize (create getter/setter methods) a property for a member variable.   I just found [this cheat sheet](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/), go down to the section called, "Properties", should give a quick overview.

Other than that [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) should give you more info.

Comment: Thanks this was just what I was looking for these two lines have save me from great grief:

[totalAmount autorelease];
 totalAmount = [input retain];

I didn't realize the iphone did not have auto garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

To define an instance variable (member), edit your `.h` file:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    // ivars go here
    NSObject *member;
}
// methods go here
@end
```

Then, in your `.m` file, from any instance method (one which begins with `-`), you can access this variable.

```
- (void)doThingWithIvar {
    [member doThing];
}
```

If you want to access the variable from *outside* the object itself, you'll need accessors. You can do this easily with Obj-C properties:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    // ivars go here
    NSObject *member;
}
// methods go here
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *member;
@end
```

And in the `.m`:

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize member;
// ...
@end
```

The `@synthesize` line creates getter/setter methods for the ivar. Then you can use property syntax:

```
MyClass *thing = ...;
NSLog(@"%@", thing.member); // getting
thing.member = obj; // setting
```

(Note that I specified `(retain)` for the `@property`; if your member isn't an Objective-C object you won't want that. And if your property's class has a mutable counterpart, you'll want `(copy)` instead.)